# Increment Rows in Excel by one (1) up to line 100, repeat until reach row 25000

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I increment the value/string in a cell by one up to row 25000
="User_"&ROW(A1)   or   =CONCATENATE("User_",ROW(A1),"@mail.com")

This works fine.

Now, my question is how do I put a conditional in where I want to increase the value for each row by one up to 100 but then want to start at one again?

User_1

User_2

User_3

'

'

User_100

User_1

User_2

'

'

User_200

User_1

'

'

User_25000

Comment: Is the very first user on Row 1?  That would make things easier

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, Actually the first row starts on Row(2) as Row(1) contains header fields

Comment: I posted an anwer but deleted because I missed something in your question - can you clarify? You want each 100th row to show the actual number but in between just 1 to 99? so around 500 the sequence goes, `98, 99, 500, 1, 2, 3` etc.....?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ROW(A1)` (or simply `ROW()`), use `IF(MOD(ROW(),100)=0,ROW,MOD(ROW,100))`

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF( MOD(ROW()-1,100)=0,ROW()-1,MOD(ROW()-1,100) )
```

If you have headers.

And with the email info it should be like:

> ="User_" & IF(MOD(ROW()-1,100)=0,ROW()-1,MOD(ROW()-1,100)) & "@mail.com"

Answer (score 0):

```
="User_"&MOD(ROW()-2,100)+1&"@mail.com"
```

The `-2`is because you said it starts on row 2, so if it starts in another row, replace the 2 with that number.

Replace the `100`with whatever number you want it to go up to before repeating.

The `+1`is to eliminate the `IF`logic needed by the other answers to this question.

Sorry this is well after the fact of the question, but hopefully it'll help someone else!

**bonus tip - if you want it to be "User_001@mail.com" (pad out the number to 3 digits), use the TEXT function like this: `="User_"&TEXT(MOD(ROW()-2,100)+1,"000")&"@mail.com"`